# Is there a way to require one file multiple times as different modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I need to share a constants between my .js and .less files. My solution for this is contain two steps:

1. Create a separate file with .const extension that contains all shared consts. It has javascript module syntax and will be executed as normal.
2. Create a loader that would change the source code depending on extension of the file that requiring this source. So if, for example, requiring .less file, then code transforms to less expressions

But i don't find the way to create two modules from one source file depending on requiring module.

My source code for conditional loader, that do the stuff:

```
module.exports = function(content, sourceMap) {
    var _ = require('lodash');
    var loaderUtils = require('loader-utils');
    var reasonResource = this._module.reasons[0].module.resource;
    var reasonResourceExtension = _.last(reasonResource.split('.'));

    switch (reasonResourceExtension)
    {
        case 'js':
        case 'const':
            var query = loaderUtils.parseQuery(this.query);
            if(query.cacheable && this.cacheable)
                this.cacheable();

            return content;
            break;
        case 'less':
            var consts = this.exec(content, this.resource);

            return JSON.stringify(consts);
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error('Not supported import .const modules from ' + reasonResourceExtension.green);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `less-loader`. It is not applying loaders, configured in `webpack.config.js`. So solution is to add ability to parametrize `less-loader` loaders list

[Pull request](https://github.com/webpack/less-loader/pull/130)

---

Then it is begin possible to write `Constants.const` with content

```
export.modules = { debug: true }
```

And then require it in `Utilities.less`

```
@import (reference) 'Const.const';
```

With this loader applied

```
module.exports = function(content, sourceMap) {
    var _ = require('lodash');
    var loaderUtils = require('loader-utils');
    var reasonResource = this._module.reasons[0].module.resource;
    var reasonResourceExtension = _.last(reasonResource.split('.'));
    var query = loaderUtils.parseQuery(this.query);

    switch (reasonResourceExtension)
    {
        case 'js':
        case 'const':
            if(query.cacheable && this.cacheable)
                this.cacheable();

            return content;
            break;
        case 'less':
            if(query.cacheable && this.cacheable)
                this.cacheable();

            var consts = this.exec(content, this.resource);
            var str = '';
            (function append(consts, prefix = '')
            {
                for (var key in consts)
                {
                    let value = consts[key];
                    if (value.constructor != Object) {
                        str += '@' + prefix + key + ': ' + toLessCssValue(consts[key]) + ';';
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('Nested objects not supported in .const files');
                    }
                }
            }(consts));

            return str;
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error('Not supported import .const modules from ' + reasonResourceExtension.green);
    }

    function toLessCssValue(value) {
        if (isNaN(value)) {
            return value;
        } else {
            return 'unit(' + value + ', px)';
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably specify a json-to-less loader (not really sure if this exists but it shouldn't be hard to write) in your less files using the require loader syntax:

```
@import "!json-to-less-loader!constants.json";
```

Then just create a less file (`constants.less`) that makes this import and exposes the constants. From there, you could just import `constants.less` as normal.

I was able to find a loader that does the opposite ([less-to-json-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-to-json-loader)). So you could use it and store your constants in a .less file and create a `constants.js` file that imports and exposes the constants in `constants.less`:

constants.less

```
@test: 20rem;
@test2: @test/2;
```

constants.js

```
module.exports = require("!less-to-json-loader!./constants.less");
```